# How can change Activity Orientation from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

Is there any way to change `Activity` orientation from `Fragment`.

I am aware about following but it's not working.

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_XYZ);
```

I put following as an Activity property and and it work.

> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

**CLOSED**

Comment: I think it should be called before setContentView. I dont think you can do it from your fragment.

Comment: I want to do it from fragment and I try to do it from onAttach ..any suggestion?

Comment: call `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` from fragment

Comment: @MichaelShrestha I tried same and it rotate as well and after display for a second it prompt error : "E/AndroidRuntime(25704): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment BPConnectionFragment{4257e310} not attached to Activity
" ..any suggestion ?